# Simplified Jones trace invariant for links

Tags: braid-groups, knot-theory, at.algebraic-topology

Jones (1985) defines a simplified trace invariant for knots by $W_K(t)=\frac{1-V_K(t)}{(1-t^3)(1-t)}$.  Then, e.g., the Arf invariant for $K$ is $Arf(K)=W_K(i)$.  Does this work for oriented links as well?  If not, is there a variant that does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops, my bad.  Since the Arf invariant is not defined for all links, what I was looking for doesn't exist.  If the Jones polynomial of an oriented link $L$ in $S^3$ equals 0 when evaluated at $t=\imath$, then the Arf invariant of $L$ is not defined.  (See W.B. Likorish, \textit{An Introduction to Knot Theory}, p. 106.)